# Is it possible to use components in FreeMarker as f.e. in Angular?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a lot of different FreeMarker templates inside my Java Spring Boot application and all of them share certain elements as for example a header and footer. Is it possible to build reusable components as one would in Angular or React?

I thought about creating elements as objects in Java and then importing them to FreeMarker as one would import text, but I thought there may be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Check the documentation about include and import. Include allows to include an template in the current one. With Import you are writing functions which can be used to output simmilar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker supports [*import*](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_import.html) and [*include*](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html).

But:

> Using include directive is almost always a bad practice, and you should  consider using the import directive instead!

I went on using *import*, more about when to use *import* [here](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html#topic.import_vs_include).

### Build components in FreeMarker with *import*

If you want to f.e. import a header component you would create a components.ftl file and create a [macro](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html) inside.

components.ftl:

```
<#macro header>
<header>
    <p>My first FreeMarker macro component header</p>
</header>
</#macro>
```

You can now import the header macro to your FreeMarker template:

template.ftl

```
<#import "template-components/components.ftl" as components>

...

<@components.header/>
```

Your header component should now display when loading the template.

*Macros* also support variables and lots more. I recommend visiting the links mentioned.